# 2Checkout integration with demo sale

Tags: django, 2checkout

Iam trying to integrate 2CO with my application using the demo sale(direct checkout method).
Now Iam stuck with an issue that even when no credit card number or cvv number is given, it redirects to the success page and returns "credit_card_processed : Y".Is there no validation applied for the card number in demo sale?

Please do guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us some code. We can't guess what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

An error message will be returned and shown on the payment form if the payment information does not authorize successfully. The buyer and sale parameters will only be returned to your approved URL if the sale is successful. You can [validate the passback](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/passback/validation) using the MD5 Hash that is included with the return parameters.